# Batch Files and Task Scheduler in Windows 8

Tags: php, csv, batch-file

I'm trying to run the batch script below every hour through task scheduler.

```
"C:\php\php.exe" -f "C:\PHP Scripts\PipedriveReadDeals.php"

Copy csv1.csv \\APACHE\csv1.csv
DEL "csv1.csv"

Copy csv2.csv \\APACHE\csv2.csv
DEL "csv2.csv"

Copy csv3.csv \\APACHE\csv3.csv
DEL "csv3.csv"

Copy csv4.csv \\APACHE\csv4.csv
DEL "csv4.csv"

Copy csv5.csv \\APACHE\csv5.csv
DEL "csv5.csv"
```

When I run the batch script normally, it works fine. It executes the `php` script, copies the files to the specified location, and delete the specified files, but when I run the script from `Task Scheduler` in `Windows 8`, the `php` script that windows is calling doesn't create the csv files, and thus, those csv files can't be copied or deleted.

I chose `Run with highest privileges` for the task, and it still won't work.

Any insight as to how to get this batch script to run every hour properly with `Task Scheduler` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any error messages from the `task scheduler`?

Comment: @RyanVincent No errors. Just says `Task Started`, `Task Completed`, `Action Completed` in my `History`

Comment: a scheduled task has a different "homedirectory" (`%windir%\system32`) So just place a `cd <wherever your files are>` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: @Stephan changing my directory solved my problem!